# MySQL Three State Attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is a question of good database design as off the top of my head, I can think of many ways to implement this, but the approaches I am coming up with are most likely poor database design (I do not want to be scolded by C.J. Date). I would like to set up a table in my MySQL database for inspection items that are part of an inspection form. The inspection form can be saved multiple times by the user before having completed all inspection items. Each item can therefore be in an "un-inspected" state, or in an "inspected" state. If an inspection item has been inspected, it must have a "pass" or "fail" value.

Originally I was going to use a single boolean attribute that allows NULL, and I was going to have NULL represent the "un-inspected" state, thinking that NULL means the value of the attribute (pass/fail) is unknown. But watching videos and reading books on database design, I am led to believe that the use of NULL to represent a state or value is poor design. I do not think using two attributes (inspected & pass) or using a three valued ENUM would be good database design either.

This may be a very elementary problem, and I may just be overcomplicating things.

Comment: What is wrong with using a boolean/bit column for each item, and just initializing the column to uninspected?  By the way, who is "C.J. Date?"

Comment: C.J. Date is a relational database expert - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_J._Date, he has a number of books and videos on relational database design.

Comment: Hey Ingo, your logo is my first computer. Must be somewhere in the attic in the old house. Cheers!

Comment: That was my first computer as well! You should dig it out and fire it up, could be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no inherent problem having a single column for "pass"/"fail" with `NULL` meaning that the status has not been assigned.  In fact, I can see a certain elegance to it, assuming that the values are well-documented, so users know what they are getting.

You *can* also use an `enum`.  To be honest, though, when using enums I often have to look up what values are acceptable (is it "pass" or "passed"?).  A bit/boolean type makes that process much easier.

So, I wouldn't stress over this particular problem.  If

- 1=pass
- 0=fail
- NULL=in progress

Then that is a reasonable interpretation.  If things get more complicated, you might want to use a reference table (or enums).

Comment: Thank you Gordon. So basically, if I named the attribute "pass", then a 1 makes "pass" TRUE, a 0 (zero) makes "pass" FALSE, and a NULL represents that the state of "pass" is un-available/unassigned since it was not yet inspected, and that would not somehow be poor form or possibly be mis-interpreted?

Comment: The definition of null means unknown, so from a pure database point of view it means "don't know if it's been not inspected, or inspected/pass, or inspected/fail". I would definitely use an inspection status value, because sure as sh*t you are going to want to add "inspection commenced", "re-inspection required",  and who knows what other status values down the track!

Comment: @Ingo . . . That is reasonable.  I would likely include columns related to the inspection -- such as inspection date and inspected by -- and these would more directly provide information on whether or not an inspection occurred.